# Best way to convert Dictionary to two lists

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, ienumerable

How to convert a Dictionary of type `Dictionary<DateTime, double>` to `Tuple<List<DateTime>, List<double>>`?

Thanks

Edit: Does the following guarantee that the order of items in both lists is identical? `var abc = new Tuple<List<DateTime>, List<double>>(_data.Keys.ToList(), _data.Values.ToList());`

Comment: might want to look at the [`Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) properties

Comment: about the order of the `Keys`and `Values` properties _The order of the keys in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated values in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection returned by the Values property_ again from the msdn pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple (The order is guaranteed):

```
Tuple<List<DateTime>, List<double>> tuple 
                   = Tuple.Create(dict.Keys.ToList(), dict.Values.ToList());
```

> the order of the values in the Dictionary.ValueCollection is unspecified, but it is the same order as
>   the associated keys in the Dictionary.KeyCollection
>   returned by the Keys property.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx)

**Example of Order guarantee:**

Order is guaranteed even after updates, removal and additions.

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

dict[2] = "2";
dict[1] = "0";
dict[3] = "3";
dict[1] = "1";
dict[1] = "1";

dict.Remove(3);

var tuple = Tuple.Create(dict.Keys.ToList(), dict.Values.ToList());
// 2 1
// "2" "1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You answered first and provided identical solutions hence my marking this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = Tuple.Create(dict.Keys.ToList(), dict.Values.ToList());
```

According to the order-question in your comment:

What order you'll get isn't guaranteed because the dictionary is not an ordered collection. But  it's guaranteed that you get the same in the `Keys`- and the `Values`-collection and if you use `foreach(KeyValuepair<DateTime,double> kv in dict)`.

[MSDN: Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The order of the keys in the Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue).KeyCollection
>   is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated values in
>   the Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue).ValueCollection returned by the Values
>   property.

[MSDN: Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The order of the values in the
>   Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue).ValueCollection is unspecified, but it is
>   the same order as the associated keys in the
>   Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue).KeyCollection returned by the Keys
>   property.

You've asked:

> So, for example, `dict[result.Item1[5]] == result.Item2[5]` holds?

Yes, that's guaranteed according to the documentation above

Comment: Does this guarantee that the order of items in both lists match the original dictionary content? If I invoke `result.Item1[5] and result.Item2[5]` will both items match one of the Dictionary entries? Will the following hold? `dict[result.Item1[5] == result.Item2[5]`

Comment: I posted an example above

Comment: @MattWolf check my answer

Comment: So, for example, `dict[result.Item1[5]] == result.Item2[5]` holds?

Comment: @MattWolf: yes, that's guaranteed according to the documentation

Comment: @MattWolf Actually i replied first, you can check the timestamps. I don't mind marking this as the answer. Not a big deal :)

Comment: @user3185569, correct, my wrong, I thank both of you for the prompt replies. Up voted both.